# Where's the 8pen Preview Popup?

Tags: keyboard

I just purchased the 8pen keyboard last night, and one frustration I'm having is that I keep having to look around my finger to figure out where the next letter is.

I found [this blog post from November](http://www.droid-life.com/2010/11/10/8pen-keyboard-updated-is-now-free-and-easier-to-use/) saying that the keyboard was now free and also updated to, among other things, include a preview popup that would show where the letters are.

The bit about the app being free is definitely outdated, as there is no free app on the marketplace and the links it includes are dead. It would seem that the preview popup is also gone.

I'm hoping someone can help me either to get the preview popup in my version (2.0.3), or help me find the version that has the preview popup.

Comment: You can ask questions about 8pen also on their official support channel at Get Satisfaction: http://getsatisfaction.com/8pen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8pen has now [answered this](http://getsatisfaction.com/8pen/topics/wheres_the_preview_popup#reply_6849249) at their official support site:

> You're right, in the early version of the 8pen from November 2010, we
>   included a popup window. It's now removed, but we are considering
>   putting it back again, as you are not the only one requesting this
>   feature.
>
> By the way, are you aware of the game "8pen Wordcup", available for
>   free on the Market ([http://goo.gl/Qvpiw](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eightpen.android.wordcup))? That should get you quickly
>   up and running with the new layout, so you won't need to be looking
>   for letters all the time.